# Port Connection Rules in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I am a beginner in Verilog

I would like to know why the port connection rules as outlined in the attached description are necessary.

Why must inputs be internally of a net type signal? And similarly, why outputs must be externally connected to a net type signal?

[image: Port Connection Rule Description]

Answer (score 3):

In Verilog, you can only do a constant assignment to a `net` type. A `reg` type is used in an `always` block to assign something based on a sensitivity list (it can be synchronous, e.g. flip-flop, or asynchronous, e.g. latch, or gate). A `net` type is used for assignments using the `assign` keyword or when connecting ports.

When you connect something to a port using the `.portName(net)` directive (or even the `instanceName(net)` method), it is a constant assignment, and hence requires the target to be a `net`.

To think of it another way:

- A `reg` type is used to store data (ish) - the value for the `reg` variable will be based on one or more inputs.
- A `net` type on the other hand is used to simply wire two things together - all parts of the net will forever be identical to the one and only input.

Answer (score 0):

When we say the inputs to a module, it means every change on input immediately affects the module, so we use the wire (net) as internal input. The input can be driven by let's say a register or a wire, as a result, externally the reg or net type can be used to connect the input.

Internal output can be a register or a wire, but when the module was instantiated, the wire needs to be connected to observe the output results. If you used a reg type, it may cause an extra clock cycle delay.

In systemVerilog, the logic type can be used in both cases. If you still confused about these types. You can directly use logic type everywhere.